# What are different/benefit between S3->Redshift and S3->EMR->Redshift?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

I have simple question what are pros/cons for import data from S3 directly into redshift and S3 to redshift via EMR. The reason that I post this question is about If I choose S3->redshift I could do transfrom in redshift using SQL. In other hand If I choose EMR that means using pig/hive or java instead of SQL. Which way I should go?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the amount of data you have to process and how much of the processing you can offload to Hadoop. Redshift has pretty good performance but it doesn't support too many concurrent operations so data transformation in Redshift may affect your user's querying performance. Also, in Hadoop you can process many types of data and file formats - Redshift is obviously more limited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer SNeumann, could you give me a use case for this reason to make me more clearer?

Answer (score 1):

I am using S3 -> Redshift, and the performance is pretty good. Like the previous comment, there is a trade off, if you dont want block the user queries, either use Redshift WLM or EMR. In Redshift WLM, your process will be throttled, where as in EMR  you will be charged for the aws resources.